# Film where half the community lived by day and the other by night

Tags: story-identification, movie

A sci-fi film, half the community lived in the day and other half lived at night.  I think it was a love story.  I think it was released between 2004 - 2010. I watched it at Grimmfest Manchester at their Halloween event.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this? Any of the plot? Presumably at a Halloween event this was a horror film? If so how was it horror? Please [edit] this to include anything else you remember.

Comment: https://grimmfest.com/archive-festivals-screenings/ Grimmfest has been running since 2009. Their archived playlist is available on the internet. Any of the names seem to ring a bell?

Comment: @Corrinne Brownhill - If my answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting buttons. I'm 99% sure it is the right film, but it's nice to have such answers confirmed with an acceptance.

Answer (score 6):

*[By Day and By Night](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1145430/)* (AKA *De día y de noche*) (2010)

[image]

Synopsis:

> Dystopian sci-fi about an over-populated world in which the solution has been to program people to operate solely in either day or night, meaning that the population are only conscious half the day and can never interact with each other.

[It was shown at Grimmfest in 2011](http://grimmfest.com/2011/09/by-day-and-by-night/).

Comment: If this answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting arrows.

Comment: Interesting - in the early '70s, Philip Jose Farmer had a story called "The Sliced Crosswise Only-on-Tuesday World" which was along the same lines, except that everyone was assigned one day each week. There was some kind of suspended animation involved that meant 6/7ths of the population was in storage at any given time. I doubt there's any connection to the movie, though.